# Rails - Getting datetime_select into user timezone for model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date, datetime

I tried to get this answered with no luck so I'll try again.

I've implemented the railcast timezone goodies to allow the user to set their time zone. It works. `Time.zone.now` gives the correct time zone. It's in here 
http://stevenyue.com/2013/03/23/date-time-datetime-in-ruby-and-rails/

I have events and have been trying to get the `datetime_select` in my form to give me a time that is also in the user's time zone.

My goal is to be able to compare it to current time (`Time.zone.now`) to validate that the start time is not before current time. And eventually end time > start time etc.

I've tired several ways including this one with no luck...

This one - he answered his own question later (is exactly my problem)

[Rails datetime_select posting my current time in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163176/rails-datetime-select-posting-my-current-time-in-utc)

```
def start_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

   if date_start.in_time_zone(Time.zone) < Time.zone.now
     errors.add(:date_start, "has already passed")
   end

end
```

The above doesn't seem to work because you can't extract `date_start` just like that. It's separated into different components, so I tried to do something like this

```
  def start_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

    date = DateTime.new(params[event][date_start(1i)].to_i, params[event][date_start(2i)].to_i, params[event][date_start(3i)].to_i, params[event][date_start(4i)].to_i, params[event][date_start(5i)].to_i)
    if date.in_time_zone < Time.zone.now
      errors.add(:date_start, "has already passed")
    end
  end
```

In my model I can't access params so I don't know how to get this to work...

I want to move to a jquery calendar/time picker if possible as I can't seem to get this work.. but any suggestions on alternatives or on this is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this line in your model:

```
validate :start_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
```

and then this method can be something like:

```
private
def start_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
  errors.add(:date_start, "has already passed") if self.date_start < Time.zone.now
end
```

[See this for more information](https://github.com/suryart/spree_active_sale/blob/master/app/models/spree/sale_event.rb#L36-L37).

Comment: yeah i copied one of my old examples but i've tried both, mine and copying his code exactly. Did you do any other setup with time zones?

Comment: Nope, it works as written in link I've posted. When you say it didn't work, did you try to inspect the value of `date_start` in method `start_date_cannot_be_in_the_past ` or is method `start_date_cannot_be_in_the_past` even being called in the first place? Have you also copied line: `validate :start_date_cannot_be_in_the_past`?

Comment: how should I inspect it in my view? it shows up in the params in my debug info within my event. I can't view `:date_start` like this `params[:event][:date_start]`. so I tried something like this `params[:event]['date_start(1i)']` to view the first part and I get a undefined [] for nilclass. And yes the validate part is in

Comment: @Clam : inside method: `start_date_cannot_be_in_the_past ` write: `puts '*'*100` and then `puts self.inspect` and see if the object has date_time with proper value.

Comment: it appears to be there. just in wrong time zone. i see the event in the server console `0 Nov 2014 00:20:00 +0000` It should be `-0800` for time zone